# iPhone dev - Navigation-based app with a start-up log-in screen?

Tags: iphone, navigation, uitableview

I'm making a navigation-based app that I want to start out with a screen that let's the user enter a username/password before continuing on to the normal navigation hierarchy of views. I'm trying to think about the best way to go about doing this. Should I create a new viewController for the log-in screen and start out with that and then use presentModalViewController to go to the RootViewController of the navigation hierarchy? Or would it be better to start out in the RootViewController (a tableViewController) and immediately push the log-in view onto the screen, and then pop it if they enter a correct username/pw combo? I'm also curious as to HOW you would start your application with a different view from the RootViewController, because right now that's always the first one that shows up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the user suspends/resumes your app or locks/unlocks the phone, are you going to make them login again?  If so, then I'd choose your second option, pushing the LoginView above the NavigationView.  Otherwise I think starting with the LoginView and replacing it with the NavigationView is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your ApplicationDelegate class specifies which controller will serve as the root controller for the application.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    ...
}
```

In this example, an instance of UINavigationController is set as the root view controller once the application has completed launching (e.g. all resources are loaded and the transition is made from the splash image).

If you want a different controller to serve as the root of your application, then this is where you'd do it.

To answer your question about the design, it depends on the desired workflow. Based on what you've described, I'd start with a barebones view controller that loads up a login view/controller. Upon authenticating the user, this view controller can switch to the main application view. With a design like this, you can easily switch back to the LoginViewController if you need to re-authenticate the user at any point.

ApplicationViewController (root)
     - LoginViewController
     - MainViewController (this could be a UINavigationController or whatever you need it to be)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused about the Navigation-based app template in general. Does it not provide you with a UINavigationController? Because RootViewController is a UITableViewController, so what do I use as the navigation controller? (where do I actually do the pushing?) Do I have to make my own navigationController? Where should I make it? I'm very confused. Thanks for any help